# Finding unique values in Array

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an array where I'm trying to find the unique values. I've seen many answers for this type of thing, but I can't understand how to apply them to my situation. Thanks in advance for the help, as I'm learning.

```
    Array([0] => Array ( [department] => value1)
          [1] => Array ( [department] => value1)
          [2] => Array ( [department] => value2)
          [3] => Array ( [department] => value2)
          [4] => Array ( [department] => value3)
          [5] => Array ( [department] => value3))
```

So I want to pull out value1, value2 and value3 so I can populate them into a select box using foreach, but I am always receiving a list showing all of the instance of each value above (value1, value1, value2, value2, value3, value3).

Comment: Why don't you do that in database? `SELECT DISTINCT department ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$departments = array();
foreach ($personnel_list as $part) {
    $departments[] = $part['department'];
}
$departments = array_unique($departments);
```

Comment: `array_map(function($i) { return $i['department']; }, $array);`

Comment: Thank you SO much!

I'm still having one issue. When I echo the results, one of the values is 'Array'. How can I get rid of that one?

Below is my final code

$personnel_list2 = $personnel_list;
foreach ($personnel_list2 as $part) {
    $personnel_list2[] = $part['department'];
}
$departments = array_unique($personnel_list2);

foreach ($departments as $depts) {
 echo '<option value="' . $depts. '">' . $depts. '</option>';
}

Comment: @NotAnotherCliche, the `foreach()` loop was meant to go over the array you posted. If that array is stored in a variable called `$personnel_list`, please see the updated answer (`foreach` loops through `$personnel_list`, then for each entry, it adds its `department` in the `$departments` array).